# Explanation of bash specific syntax

Tags: bash

Came across this piece of code:

```
for entry in $(echo $tmp | tr ';' '\n')
do
echo $entry
  rproj="${entry%%,*}"
  rhash="${entry##*,}"
  remoteproj[$rproj]=$rhash
done
```

So I do understand that initially ';' is converted to new line so that all entries in the file are on a separate line. However, I am seeing this for the first time:

```
rproj="${entry%%,*}"
rhash="${entry##*,}"
```

I do understand that this is taking everything before ',' and after comma ',' . But, is this more efficient than split? Also, if someone please explain the syntax because I am unable to relate this to regular expression or bash syntax.

Comment: what is `split`? string manipulation in bash: check [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) or [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) or [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073).

Comment: @anishsane. I see, think i used perl's split here in bash and was trying to compare it with that. Thanks for the links, helped.

Comment: Go with @anishsane's second or third link. Avoid the first (ABS) one. It just adds distracting, pointless examples like `echo \`expr...\``, which you should never use in a bash script anyway.

Comment: The code you've found here is rather poorly written btw. doing `for entry in $(anycmd)` is a [bad practice](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: It's not `bash`-specific; Both `${var%%word}` and `${var##word}` are part of the POSIX shell specification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are [string manipulation operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

```
${string##substring}
```

> Deletes longest match of $substring from front of $string.

Meaning it will remove everything before the first comma, including it

```
${string%%substring}
```

> Deletes longest match of $substring from back of $string.

Meaning it will remove everything after the last comma, including it

---

Btw, I would use the internal field separator instead of the `tr` command:

```
IFS=';'
for entry in $tmp ; do
    echo $entry
    rproj="${entry%%,*}"
    rhash="${entry##*,}"
    remoteproj[$rproj]=$rhash
done
unset IFS
```

Like [this](http://mindspill.net/computing/linux-notes/using-the-bash-ifs-variable-to-make-for-loops-split-with-non-whitespace-characters/).

Comment: Don't see a down vote. Thanks for the explanation and the suggested improvement.

Comment: You are welcome! There are currently two ups and one downvote.. Would like to know what the secret guy has to say. Probably interesting. However, probably it was simply by accident.

Comment: Some people object to using `IFS` in that way.  I don't, and I have experienced a down vote for suggesting it.  It would have been polite to say so though.  `unset IFS` could have other side effects in a large script, so saving the old value then restoring it might have been safer, but that's nick-picking and a matter of opinion.

Comment: In general, you should restore `IFS` to its previous value, not simply unset it.

Comment: @chepner Looks like you are right. While `unset` works to reset the IFS back to it's initial state, it would not set it to it's *previous* state, which could have been manipulated by the script already. Good point! I just wanted to keep things as simple as possible, probably too simple.

Comment: Yeah, restoring `IFS` to its previous value correctly is ugly and cumbersome to do 100% correctly. Usually, it's best to localize any changes to a subshell instead of changing its value globally.

Comment: Actually, in `bash` 4.2, it's not so bad: `[[ -v IFS ]] && OLD_IFS="$IFS"` to save, `[[ -v OLD_IFS ]] && IFS="$OLD_IFS"` to restore.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `read` command both to split the line original line and to split each entry.

```
IFS=';' read -r -a entries <<< "$tmp"
for entry in "${entries[@]}"; do
    IFS=, read -r rproj rhash <<< "$entry"
    remoteproj["$rproj"]=$rhash
done
```

Comment: Your usage of `IFS` looks better than my since your localized the IFS changes to the `read` command - in contrast to my which changes the global IFS for the whole current script.

Answer (score 1):

For performance it is best to do things without subshells. I am still getting confused between % and #, but these internal evaluations are way better than using `sed`, `cut` or `perl`.
The %% means "remove the largest possible matching string from the end of the variable's contents".
The ## means "remove the largest possible matching string from the beginning of the variable's contents".

You can see the working with a simple test:

```
for entry in key,value a,b,c
do
   echo "$entry is split into ${entry%%,*} and ${entry##*,}"
done
```

The result of splitting key,value is obvious. When you are splitting a,b,c the field b is lost.